# no matches for kind "OpenTelemetryCollector" in version "opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: kubernetes, logging, open-telemetry, observability

I tried instrumenting the open telemetry by deploying the following script.

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: Instrumentation
metadata:
  name: my-instrumentation
spec:
  exporter:
    endpoint: http://simplest-collector-headless:14250
  propagators:
    - tracecontext
    - baggage
    - b3
  sampler:
    type: parentbased_traceidratio
    argument: "0.25"
```

I got the following error thrown during the deployment.

```
 no matches for kind "Instrumentation" in version "opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "OpenTelemetryCollector" in version "opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1"]
```

The official open telemetry doc says opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1 has the kind OpenTelemetryCollector. I am stuck debugging this issue.

Any hints on the same will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The CRDs are missing/haven't been installed.

You need to install them which should happen automatically when using a helm chart repository and not passing `--skip-crds`:
https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/custom_resource_definitions/